# Google Sheets (Formula or GAScript) - Combine 2 sheets with unique columns into a single sheet

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

### The Problem

I am trying to combine Sheet1 & Sheet2 into Sheet3 sorted by timestamp, but I am unable to adjust the columns so they match between both datasets. Is this even possible with using formulas, or is my only option Google App Scripts?

### My Attempt

`=query({Sheet1!A2:F;Sheet2!A2:F},"WHERE Col1 is not null ORDER BY Col1")`

I have also tried other methods using helper columns, but that did not work very well either.

**Spreadsheet:**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w1RIygC4GodoIvzBGKbx5P_GwSqBMPJ6AkL8Dl5ZLOU/edit?usp=sharing

#### Sheet1

| Timestamp | First Name | Email | Address | Phone Number | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/15/2022 8:12:00 | Jed | JedRigby@ | 123 St | (778) 913-4767 | Comment A |
| 3/15/2022 9:23:00 | Elle-May | Elle-MayMcdermott@ | 124 St | (660) 632-5480 | Comment B |
| 3/15/2022 10:11:00 | Junayd | JunaydDavis@ | 125 St | (774) 516-6738 | Comment C |
| 3/19/2022 19:55:04 | Caleb | CalebMaddox@ | 128 St | (624) 540-7406 | Comment D |
| 3/19/2022 22:17:04 | Misbah | MisbahHowarth@ | 129 St | (890) 436-0537 | Comment E |

#### Sheet2

| Timestamp | First Name | Last Name | Email | Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/15/2022 13:37:00 | Jody | English | JodyEnglish@ | 126 St |
| 3/19/2022 17:32:04 | Samual | Savage | SamualSavage@ | 127 St |
| 3/22/2022 7:24:04 | Bill | Short | BillShort@ | 130 St |
| 3/22/2022 9:51:04 | Jevon | Conner | JevonConner@ | 131 St |
| 3/22/2022 12:33:04 | Clementine | Talley | ClementineTalley@ | 132 St |

#### COMBINED (Sheet1 & Sheet2) - Expected Reults

| Timestamp | First Name | Last Name | Email | Address | Phone Number | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/15/2022 8:12:00 | Jed | Rigby | JedRigby@ | 123 St | (778) 913-4767 | Comment A |
| 3/15/2022 9:23:00 | Elle-May | Mcdermott | Elle-MayMcdermott@ | 124 St | (660) 632-5480 | Comment B |
| 3/15/2022 10:11:00 | Junayd | Davis | JunaydDavis@ | 125 St | (774) 516-6738 | Comment C |
| 3/15/2022 13:37:00 | Jody | English | JodyEnglish@ | 126 St | (492) 298-3670 |  |
| 3/19/2022 17:32:04 | Samual | Savage | SamualSavage@ | 127 St | (871) 816-6015 |  |
| 3/19/2022 19:55:04 | Caleb | Maddox | CalebMaddox@ | 128 St | (624) 540-7406 | Comment D |
| 3/19/2022 22:17:04 | Misbah | Howarth | MisbahHowarth@ | 129 St | (890) 436-0537 | Comment E |
| 3/22/2022 7:24:04 | Bill | Short | BillShort@ | 130 St | (660) 632-5480 |  |
| 3/22/2022 9:51:04 | Jevon | Conner | JevonConner@ | 131 St | (549) 806-8647 |  |
| 3/22/2022 12:33:04 | Clementine | Talley | ClementineTalley@ | 132 St | (660) 632-5480 |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({QUERY({Sheet1!A2:F, REGEXEXTRACT(Sheet1!C2:C, Sheet1!B2:B&"(.*)@")}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col7,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6");
 QUERY(Sheet2!A2:F, "select A,B,C,D,E,F,' ' label ' '''")}, 
 "where Col1 is not null order by Col1", ))
```

[image]